# How to get list of version changed files for magento Update

Tags: magento

My client has Enterprise edition 1.9 and have to update it to newer version, but the problem is the existing code is having core changes and we need to find it all. Is there any tool or command line except **SVN,linux Meld, bcompare** on windows(because these are just showing the files separately and does not giving the list of changed files).

I need the list of files that are changed/modified/deleted/newly added. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `diff` tool. This is a fairly common thing to need to do to two sets of code, so look for a Windows-friendly diff program to run against the two copies of the codebase. On linux, the utility is called (wait for it...) `diff`.

Keep in mind that these tools will show any changes to the local codepool, as well as changes you've made to core files. If you have made such core changes (bad! bad!), diff against a clean copy of Magento to see the upgrade differences.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks for the @Joseph. Am using Ubuntu, is it available on it, can i find it in Repository Manager. Let me check it out.

Comment: Yes, diff is a standard command in terminal if I recall correctly.